# Java Properties File Creation

Tags: java

I am using the following logic to create a properties file which saves a sql query. Everytime the query is saved, the file gets an extra character added to the query.

```
    String filePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload"); 
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(""+filePath+"/cem_inventory.properties");

    props.setProperty("query", select);

    props.store(fos, "Properties file generated from Java program");

    fos.close();
```

The Query should give the output as : `SELECT *  FROM CEM_INVENTORY_TEMP WHERE 1 = 1  AND Status in ('Deployed');`

But what I am getting is `SELECT *  FROM CEM_INVENTORY_TEMP WHERE 1 \= 1  AND Status in ('Deployed');`

Comment: The one snippet is incomplete

Comment: `=` is a reserved char in property files (key **=** value), can't you use plaintext here?

Comment: But what happens when you read it back?

Comment: it's being escaped, as RC mentioned, i think when u read it using `Properties` again, it may be normal. but why don;t you save in a regular text file?

Comment: What you are seeing is normal and correct behavior.  The *actual* character is still just `=`;  some characters can be (or have to be) escaped in a properties file.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader- .

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing a backslash before the = symbol is because the = symbol is a reserved character. Java still lets you sore data with these characters in it tho and the backslash is it’s way of saying: “This is a special character, just treat it as text and nothing else!”. When you read the file back Java will not include this backslash in the final String.